# How to declare variables outside procedure in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm new to mariadb coding and stuck while declaring variables outside a procedure in mariadb. Is it possible to declare variables globally, i.e., outside any procedure or function in mariadb and if yes, how can that be done?

Comment: I think we need an example of your code and some idea of SPECIFICALLY what you are trying to do

Comment: A session variable is probably enough for you, but see the duplicate topic for answers on both session and global variables.